# Firebase admin SDK Python - cannot verify custom tokens

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-admin

I'm trying to play with the firebase admin sdk for python for making custom tokens and verify those while testing my app. Problem is that while I try to verify the token I always get such an error:

```
ValueError: Firebase ID token has incorrect "aud" (audience) claim. Expected "my_project_id" but got "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit". Make sure the ID token comes from the same Firebase project as the service account used to authenticate this SDK. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for details on how to retrieve an ID token.
```

I followed the guide to create the app and making the tokens:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import auth, credentials

cred = credentials.Certificate('/path/to/file.json')
app = firebase_admin.initialize(cred)
custom_token = auth.create_custom_token('some-uid', app=app)
auth.verify_id_token(custom_token, app=app)
```

and here I get the error. It seems that _TokenGenarator is initialised with the defaults that are coming back from the error. I thought when passing the app it should automatically change those but it's not happening. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`verify_id_token()` only accepts ID tokens. Custom tokens do not fall into that category. See this [test case](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python/blob/master/tests/test_auth.py#L250). Raising a `ValueError` is the expected behavior in this case.

ID tokens can be obtained from a [client SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients). You can exchange a custom token for an ID token by calling one of the provided `signInWithCustomToken()` methods.

Comment: Signing in with custom tokens: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#sign_in_using_custom_tokens_on_clients

Comment: So `signInWithCustomToken()` is not available in python right? Is it only available in mobile development?

Comment: Right. It's not available in any of the Admin SDKs.

Comment: Would using Swift work to access firebase on desktop through tokens work? I see swift can be used on windows and aws too, and the token signin is available in the firebase-ios-sdk.

Answer (score 0):

You can use REST API endpoint to exchange you custom token to id token https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/use-rest-api

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).